# Did I brick my laptop trying to uninstall Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall, boot-repair

I had Ubuntu dual booting and wanted to remove it. I followed the instructions at "[How to Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/)" It says "it is hard" to tell which partition [(the 2 unnamed partitions it will not let me remove)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qep8G.png) to remove but did my best to avoid the recovery one.

I then loaded from a Recovery Disk... and at the CMD promt enter the bootrec.exe /fixmbr and it is successful.

But, when I restart it still goes to the "grub" command line and that is all I can do.

My guess is that I removed the ubuntu partition but not the "grub" partition or something?

If I load from the Recovery Disk I can't do anything because every option just restarts the computer then back to the grub line?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what version of windows you are using but you could try putting in the disc and try the repair .. it should overwrite the grub and reinstall the windows boot loader.

If you are using Windows 10 you click on the repair link then troubleshoot.. then advanced options finally start up repair and it should have one entry with your windows listed choose that and it should repair your booting issue. It should not restart and go back to the grub line if you do this..

Hopefully this will work for you.